# Android web app: How to handle circles?

Tags: android, css, performance, svg

I must do an **HTML app** on **Android** and I wonder, in 2016 what's the best way to handle **circles**?

1. **SVG**: They will be crisp, but I fear poor
   performances. *Is this still true or is that an old myth?*
2. **PNG**: Less crisp and will require a lot of images if circles are not all the same size, but probably easier to handle for the
   browser.
3. **Border-radius**: Will the circles be crisp and again, I am afraid  of poor performances if the browser has to calculate a lot of them.

The app will only be running on Android **Lollipop** and up.
Circles will have **CSS transitions** on them *(Scale, opacity, etc)* and will contain html short descriptions *(Home, About, etc).*
Anyone have recommandations?

Comment: I think more information is required.  Are these animated circles, static? containing content? what exactly is it that you're looking for.

Comment: @JohnBoker Good points. Yes, the circles will have CSS transitions on them and yes, they will have content _(Mostly short desciptions)_. I'll add those infos in my question. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what would have better performance, but i'd probably go with the border-radius version.  I've not seen problems using border-radius and this would probably be the easiest of the options.